# iText pdf how to extract image decoded with JBIG2Decode filter

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Does anybody know how to extract an image using iText html2Pdf library which is a monochromatic scan of a page? According to this page:
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/which-image-types-are-supported-by-itext
this library supports such mode /JBIG2. But when I try to extract such page, it shows me an error:
iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException: 'Filter /JBIG2Decode is not supported.'

I am using C# for doing this.

Here is my code sample:

```cs
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
try
{
    using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
        {
            PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPdfObject();
            PdfDictionary pageResources = pageDict.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources);
            PdfDictionary pageXObjects = pageResources.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);
            PdfName imgName = pageXObjects.KeySet().First();
            PdfStream imgStream = pageXObjects.GetAsStream(imgName);
            imgStream.SetData(reader.ReadStreamBytesRaw(imgStream));
                        
            PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
            array.Add(PdfName.JBIG2Decode);
            imgStream.Put(PdfName.Filter, array);

            result = imgStream.GetBytes();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, as of now, you can only place JBIG2 images on PDFs with iText, not extract them